# convert a php file to html and save it on server

Tags: php

I've made a website with news, its called index.php and it gets it content using php from database. Is it possible to convert this site to pure html, ie without all the php database queries, but with only the ouptup as the user sees it after entering the website ?

Comment: You want the extension of index.php to look like index.html? Or you want to hardcode all the data to index.html? Or you want to do some XML trick?

Comment: @Fallen Basically i want this site to be a html file and look like a website that user can save on their computer, that all the php queries are turned into content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Begin your code with:

```
<?php
ob_start(function($c) {
    file_put_contents("your_html_file_here.html",$c);
    return $c;
});
```

With this in place, all output is saved to a file, as well as sent to the browser - you can then use this file however you need.

For older versions of PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start(create_function('$c','file_put_contents("your_html_file_here.html",$c); return $c;'));
```

Comment: It seems like there is an syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in your code, but thanks ill try to get it to work

Comment: Seems to me like you're using an ancient version of PHP. You should update ;) We're on 5.5 now!

Answer (score 0):

yes, combination of ob_start and ob_get_flush can be used.

This will look like:

```
ob_start();

//Your code goes here, you can include, require

$sOutput = ob_get_flush();

//Here you can do whatever you want with output

file_put_contents ('index.html', $sOutput);
```